# Obstruction to the splitness of an exact sequence of holomorphic vector bundles

Tags: vector-bundles

In the book of S. Kobayashi, hyperbolic complex spaces, there is the lemma (3.A.3) on the page 153, section Royden's extension lemma, whose statement is

> Every exact sequence of holomorphic vector bundles $0\to E'\to E\to E''\to 0$ on a Stein manifold splits.

The author's argument is that the obstruction to a splitting lies in $H^1(X,\mathrm{Hom}(E'',E'))$ which is zero since $X$ is a Stein manifold.

Could someone explain what obstruction means and why it lies in this cohomology group? Thank you very much.