# Obstruction to the splitness of an exact sequence of holomorphic vector bundles

Tags: vector-bundles

This question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343066/obstruction-to-the-splitness-of-an-exact-sequence-of-holomorphic-vector-bundles), but I think there will not be an answer, so let me recopy the question on Mathoverflow.

In the book of S. Kobayashi, hyperbolic complex spaces, there is the lemma (3.A.3) on the page 153, section Royden's extension lemma, whose statement is

> Every exact sequence of holomorphic vector bundles $0\to E'\to E\to E''\to 0$ on a Stein manifold splits.

The author's argument is that the obstruction to a splitting lies in $H^1(X,\mathrm{Hom}(E'',E'))$ which is zero since $X$ is a Stein manifold.

Could someone explain what obstruction means and why it lies in this cohomology group? Thank you very much.

Comment: In a sense, this is the beginning of homological algebra: extensions are classified by an appropriate $\operatorname{Ext}$.

Comment: There are a lot of possible points of view for explaining this. The one I prefer goes true the hermitian theory and the second fundamental form. You can find it here https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf on page 275.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, it's quite interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the standard procedure. Tensor with dual of $E''$ to get,

$$0\to E''^*\otimes E'\to E''^*\otimes E\to E''^*\otimes E''\to 0.$$

Applying global sections, we get a map $H^0(E''^*\otimes E'')\to H^1(E''^*\otimes E')$. The image of the natural 'identity' element in the first vector space gives an element in the second, called an obstruction. If this element is zero (as in the case of a Stein manifold, where $H^1=0$), then the identity element can be lifted to $H^0(E''^*\otimes E)$ and easy to check that this means your exact sequence splits.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried some computations according  to your message and found it very elementary.