# Direct sum of quotient bundle and the subbundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, vector-bundles

There is a very useful slogan that those constructions involving vector spaces which are canonical (does not require any choices) does carry on to vector bundles as well. 
I would like to confront this with one particular example: let $E$ be a vector bundle over $X$ and $V$ be a subbundle of $E$. We can form the quotient bundle $E/V$. My question is:

> Do we have an isomorphism $E \cong V \oplus E/V$? If so, does this isomorphism is canonical?

Comment: It is not canonical even if X Is a point.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are in the differentiable category. Let $g$ be a differentiable metric on $E$, you can define $V'$ the orthogonal bundle of $V$. The restriction of the canonical projection $p:E\rightarrow E/V$ to $V'$ is an isomorphism.

In the complex category, this is not necessarily true, there exists an obstruction in $H^1(X,)$ which is the obstruction of such a splitting.

Comment: To clarify: This is *not* canonical. (Also, where does the obstruction live in the holomorphic category?)

Comment: I don't have the answer in mind, but you can read Atiyah, to have the exact answer. There is an old paper of him on the question  written in the 50's 60's ?, in which it is defined the so-called Atiyah class.

Comment: Since Tsemo can't be bothered to make his answer complete, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1345658/71348) is a reference in MSE.